# empty line in a p. line-height seems not to work

Tags: css, line-height

i am trying to add empty space between lines  in a html title:
I really cant figure out where my problem is... :-(
The html is:

```css
.col1 {
  width: 10%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.col2 {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
}

.col3 {
  width: 10%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.title {
  background-color: orange;
  font-size: 34px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class=col1>a</div>
<div class=col2>
  <h2>
    <p class=title>
      long, longgfdfdg, long, longgfdfdg, long, longgfdfdg, long, longgfdfdg, long, longgfdfdg, long, longgfdfdg,
    </p>
  </h2>
</div>
<div class=col3>a</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uvkqt7wj/

Thanks for your precious help

Comment: Can you describe a bit more clearly what you are trying to achieve :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you set the value of the line height to *a multiple of the **`font-size`*** value then you will get what I think from your question is your desired end-point height.

So your font size is 34px. This is `line-height: 1`, so to add a 34px space, you have `line-height: 2` (twice the font-size value).

You can set any digital value here without a unit, such as `line-height 1.5` which is (34px + (34px /2 ) ).

I assume the below is what you're trying to achieve with your question. Please let me know if I've misunderstood you, and clarifty your question.

```css
.col1 {
  width: 10%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.col2 {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
}

.col3 {
  width: 10%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.title {
  background-color: orange;
  font-size: 34px;
  line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class=col1>a</div>
<div class=col2>
  <h2>
    <p class=title>
      long, longgfdfdg, long, longgfdfdg, long, longgfdfdg, long, longgfdfdg, long, longgfdfdg, long, longgfdfdg,
    </p>
  </h2>
</div>
<div class=col3>a</div>
```

[This article](https://joshnh.com/weblog/how-does-line-height-actually-work/) about how CSS `Line-height` actually works is also worth a read

Answer (score -3):

your code is completely correct except that line-height css property.
you cannot give it in pixels.
line-height property value has to be entered without 'px'.
simply write:

Your Code:

```
line-height:60px;
```

Convert it to:

```
line-height:6;
```

Here You Go:

```
.title{
    background-color:orange;
    font-size:34px;
    line-height:3;
}
```

- Note don't enter keep smaller value

Comment: line-height works with pixel values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height